# MS ACCESS. Не включается меню условного форматирования

Tags: ms-access, форматирование

На форме размещена подчиненная табличная форма. Надо выделять в поле "Дата" записи которые равны завтрашнему дню. Пробовал 2 варианта:

1. Виделить столбец "Дата" в режиме Формы. На вкладке "Режим таблицы" нажать "Условное форматирование". Окно параметров УФ не открылось.
2. В режиме Конструктора выбрать контрол "Дата". На вкладке "Формат" нажать "Условное форматирование". Окно параметров УФ не открылось.

Как активировать меню условного форматирования?